# "וַיַּאֲמֵן הָעָם וַיִּשְׁמְעוּ" - believing before hearing?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashas-shemos

[Shemot 4, 31](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%90)

> "וַיַּאֲמֵן הָעָם וַיִּשְׁמְעוּ כִּי פָקַד ה' אֶת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְכִי רָאָה אֶת עָנְיָם וַיִּקְּדוּ וַיִּשְׁתַּחֲוּוּ"

This is close to "נעשה ונשמע".
How believing can come before hearing from Moses?

Comment: It seems that you may, partially, be answering your own question. The notion is not impossible, esp. for a people that have some faith in G-d. Also, I think there's another nuance in the word וַיַּאֲמֵן that means something other than just belief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Midrash](https://www.mayim.org.il/?parasha=%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%AA%D7%99#gsc.tab=0) (also discussed in [Did Moshe need to do all 3 signs for the Jewish people and if so why?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65702/did-moshe-need-to-do-all-3-signs-for-the-jewish-people-and-if-so-why)) in Shemos Rabbah 5:13 seems to imply that originally the belief was thought to be based on the signs performed, but the Passuk explains that they were later/actually based on the mention of "Pakod Yifkod":

> "ויעש האותות לעיני העם" (שמות ד ל) – מה שאמר למעלה. "ויאמן העם" – עָשׂוּ, כמו שאמר הקב"ה: "ושמעו לקולך" (שם ג יח). יכול לא האמינו עד שראו האותות? לא! אלא "וישמעו כי פקד ה' " – על השמועה האמינו ולא על ראיית האותות. ובמה האמינו? על סימן הפקידה שאמר להם, שכך היה מסורת בידם מיעקב שיעקב מסר את הסוד ליוסף ויוסף לאחיו ואשר בן יעקב מסר את הסוד לסרח בתו ועדיין היתה היא קיימת. וכך אמר לה: כל גואל שיבוא ויאמר לבני: "פקוד פקדתי אתכם", הוא גואל של אמת. כיון שבא משה ואמר: "פקוד פקדתי אתכם", מיד: "ויאמן העם". במה האמינו? כי שמעו הפקידה, זהו שכתוב: "וישמעו כי פקד ה' את בני ישראל וכי ראה את עניים ויקדו וישתחוו". ויקדו – על הפקידה, וישתחוו – על כי ראה את עניים.

RDZ Hoffman [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/4.31#e0n7) seems to imply that Vayaamen Haam and Vayishmeu are to be read together, and that the understanding of the Passuk is that they believed (written in two different ways) that Hashem had remembered his nation.  While this also technically answers the question, it is very hard to read in to the Pesukim.

The [Septuagint](https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/greek-texts/septuagint/chapter.asp?book=2&page=4) explains it to mean and they rejoiced, as in the word Vayismechu, see RDZ Hoffman above.

Comment: Thank you for finding this. The order still should be hearing first and then believing. They heard "פקוד פקדתי" and then realized that was the Geulah, but the Posuk says the opposite? By second, do you mean "וישמעו" means believed? Like in where?

Comment: @AlBerko וישמעו means both they "heard" as well as "understood". See comparable usages as in *Na'aseh Venishma* _ We will do and understand as well as *Shema Yisra'el* - Understand.

Comment: I wasn't sure myself, I figured I'd leave it to you, but here's what I think - either 1. (My chiddush) that the Vayaamen Haam refers to the believing @Alberko from the signs, and Vayishmeu afterwards confirmed it, similar to what we have in other versions of this Midrash, where she first says not to believe him, then says to once she hears Pakod Yifkod, or 2. (simple understanding) that Vayishmeu is **an explanation of why they believed**, because they heard.

Comment: @Alberko, why not look up the RDZ Hoffman at the link I provided where he gives examples?

Comment: What's weird, that נעשה ונשמע got everyone's attention and lots of interpretations, while this one (much earlier) got away unnoticed.

Comment: @alberko Perhaps because this has nothing to do with Matan Torah? (Btw, thanks for accepting, I guess you really liked the Septuagint quote and implied Kefirah lol.)

Answer (score 2):

[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.4.31?lang=bi&with=Alshich&lang2=en) translates וַיַּאֲמֵן as "were convinced." It's a possible translation, but, personally, it didn't "convince" me :-) until I read Alshich's explanation (excerpt):

> וז"א פקד פקדתי אתכם שפקוד את השכינה הוא בטחון שפקדתי אתכם וגו' והנה
>   היה אפשר שעל שמעם פקידה כפולה היתה האמנה או על האותות שאחרי דברי
>   השליחות אמר כי לא הוצרך זה כי הנה תחלה ויאמן העם כאיש אחד שעל כן לא
>   נאמר ויאמינו ואח"כ וישמעו את הפקידה כפולה שהיא כי פקד ה' את בני ישראל

paraphrasing - Previously, G-d had said "I have redeemed you and what has been done to you in Egypt, and I said that I shall go up with you from Egypt. (Shemot 3:16-17)" So, they were already promised that the Shechina (G-d's presence would go up with them out of Egypt. At this point, Aharon showed them the "wonders". Technically, the wonders convinced them and affirmed their belief in the initial statement. Then, they heard the additional statement, that G-d redeemed the people, stated by Aharon and that's when they bowed.

Answer (score 2):

Malbim (there) explains that ויאמן means that they believed that Moshe was a prophet (because of the miracles he did), and they then proceeded to listen to his prophecy.

Similarly, the Netsiv writes (there) that the belief was that Hashem appeared to Moshe.

Ibn Ezra (second commentary to the verse found [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/4.31#e0n7)), however, understands that the verse is not written linearly, and the belief happened after they listened.