# The signs at the burning bush

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, passover, tanach, yetziat-mitzrayim

In the book of shemot (chapter 4:9) hashem demonstrates to Moshe 3 separate miracles as proof that he appeared to him. The third one involving water from the Nile being transformed into blood. 
Is there any meforshim who say that hashem was also showing his awareness about the massacre that was the throwing of Jewish baby's in the above mentioned River.
Also if there's any significance in general about all 3 signs in how they relate to each other and pertain to the overall Geulah of the exodus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ibn Ezra there](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/4.9#e0n7) says that this was simply a portion of the first Makkah, the plague of blood.  This is nicely tied in with the oft-quoted (see [here](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%AA%20%D7%93%D7%9D%3F%20%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)) Midrash (Mishnas Rabbi Eliezer 19) which says that the Egyptians were punished with Makkas Dam because they threw the Jewish boys into the Nile.

See [my answer here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88289/16354) which gives some opinions on the connectivity of these three signs.