# Who did the signs in front of the people in Shmos 4 (30)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-shemos, aharon

[Shmos 4 (30)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.4.30?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en) says

> וַיְדַבֵּ֣ר אַהֲרֹ֔ן אֵ֚ת כָּל־הַדְּבָרִ֔ים אֲשֶׁר־דִּבֶּ֥ר ה׳
> אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֑ה וַיַּ֥עַשׂ הָאֹתֹ֖ת לְעֵינֵ֥י הָעָֽם׃
>
> Aaron repeated all
> the words that the LORD had spoken to Moses, and he performed the
> signs in the sight of the people ..

which suggests that Aaron did the signs as indeed is proposed by

[Ibn Ezra to 5(1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.5.1?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en) says

> ואחר. אחר שעשה אהרן את האותות באו שניהם אל פרעה.
>
> And after. After
> Aaron did the signs, the two of them came to Pharoah.

But the [HaEmek Dovor to 4 (30)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.4.30?lang=bi&with=Haamek%20Davar&lang2=he) says

> ויעש האתת וגו׳. כמו שאמר ה׳ ואת המטה הזה תקח בידך אשר תעשה בו את האתת.
> אפי׳ כשיהי׳ אהרן עמו:
>
> And he did the signs etc. As Hashem said, and this staff you shall
> take in your hand with which you shall do the signs, even when Aaron
> was with him.

Sefaria offers a translation of the [Chizkuni to 4 (30)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.4.30?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Chizkuni%2C_Exodus.4.30.1&lang2=bi) which has Moshe doing the signs although I do not see Moshe mentioned in the original Hebrew.

> ויעש האתת מהנחש ומידו ומהמים.  ויעש האותות,
>
> “Moses performed the three miracles;” the staff turning into a snake,
> his hand becoming smitten with the skin disease known as tzoraat, and
> turning water into blood.

[Malbim to 4(30)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.4.30?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en) says

> וידבר אהרן. אהרן דבר אל ב"י וה' דבר אל משה כנ"ל פט"ו וכן עשיית האותות
> היו ע"י אהרן בצוויו של משה:
>
> And Aaron spoke. Aaron spoke to the Jewish people and Hashem spoke to
> Moshe as stated above and the signs were done by Aaron at Moshe's
> command.

SUMMARY:

IBN EZRA        Aaron

HAEMEK DOVOR    Moshe

CHIZKUNI        Moshe (?)

MALBIM      Aaron

Are there other views? Is there a traditional accepted view?

related: [Did Moshe need to do all 3 signs for the Jewish people and if so why?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65702/did-moshe-need-to-do-all-3-signs-for-the-jewish-people-and-if-so-why)

Comment: I see Aharon in the passuk, yes, but given that Hashem said Moshe should do it, I’m not sure how anyone could argue differently. Oh, and Moshe is in the passuk: אשר דבר ה׳ אל **משה** ויעש וגו׳